# building a BST using Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-search-tree

*This is probably an extremely trivial question:*

I'm building an abstract BST using prolog for a school extra credit. I'm extremely new to Prolog and I can't quite picture how to do something like this.

The BST is created in the form of either a `leaf` or a `node(X,L,R)`, with `L` being the left, or lesser, BST, and `R` being the right, or greater, BST.

I've only been provided with the features of the BST as predicates, such as `card(BST, Card)`, which returns `Card` as the number of elements in the tree. So something like `card(node(1,leaf,leaf),Card)` should return `1`.

I'm can't quite wrap my head around how to start. My thought is that `leaf` and `node` are separate predicates. But how do I even "tie" them together? How would I define the rules of `node`?

Comment: What's the meaning of `X`? `leaf` wouldn't be a predicate. It's just an atom that represents a leaf node. In Prolog, predicates aren't called like functions. So `card(node(1, leaf, leaf), Card)` doesn't *return* 1. Rather, it is a query that succeeds with `Card` instantiated to 1. You can ensure this by simply asserting the fact, `card(node(_, leaf, leaf), 1)`. You can define a recursive rule for `card(node(X, L, R), Cards)`, perhaps with more than one clause, which says how `Cards` might be determined. But it's your extra credit problem, not mine, so i don't want to give away too much. :)

Comment: X is the data, and int